# Is "in the first place better used to emphasize one fact than combined with “in the second place" to introduce a series of facts?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I used to think that "in the first place" is to emphasizs something. When we see it in the middle of a paragraph, we won't expect "in the second place".

But I then saw several cases of "in the first place....in the second place" used to organize sentences. Are they good to show up together to introduce a series of reasons or facts?

Answer (score 3):

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/place) has the sentence-organising (pragmatic marker, often just 'firstly' or 'first') usage (5b, below)

> **place**
>
> (5):  relative position in a scale or series: as
>
> a :  position in a social scale (kept them in their place)
>
> b :  a  step  in a sequence (in the first place, it's none of your
>   business)
>
> c :  a  position at the conclusion of a competition (finished in last [/first]
>   place)

You may be confusing this with usage 5c here, but note the exclusion of the article there.

It's more likely, however, that you're thinking of another usage of 'in the first place' which seems to straddle the pragmatic-adverbial function:

> We should never have bought the house in the first place.

This may be read as a comment by the speaker (and certainly adding emphasis - 'Cutting to the chase, we should never have bought the house.'),

or a time reference: ('We only had four of these glasses in the first place, and now I've broken two of them.' _ Cambridge Idioms Dictionary).